# Can´t get real ads from AdMob in Ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad, admob

I can't get the real ads to work, in the xcode simulator i can see the test ads,now i'm using Xib and AdViewController to display the ad.

This are the message that i recieve: 
Unable to fill ad request.  This is a common situation.
AdMob: Did fail to receive ad in AdViewController

I need some help wiith this issue because i'm stuck, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get real ads in your real, submitted app. On the simulator, only the test ad to show that things are working.

Answer (score 0):

When using the simulator you'll get a mix of situations. Sometimes you'll get test ads and things will work. Sometimes you'll actually get simulated errors. The latter is so that you can test your code so that it can handle all situations when dealing with ads.